# Yii 2 replacement for CSecurityManager class

Tags: php, encryption, yii, yii2

I have some data in DB that is encrypted using Yii::app()->securityManager->encrypt method from CSecurityManager class.

Now I have Yii 2 application and this class does not exist in Yii2. There is yii\base\Security class with encryptByKey/decryptByKey methods but I'm not sure how to use it to correctly decrypt existing data.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Use Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html

Comment: I know about that class, wrote it in question, but could not decrypt data already encrypted with securityManager class. Algorithms are quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *Yii 2* was designed, backward compatibility was a secondary consideration. *Yii 2* is a completely different code base, redesigned from the ground up. The developers were aiming to create the best framework that they can rather than maintain maximum backwards compatibility. Among these changes the encryption/decryption method in *Yii 1* and *Yii 2* are not compatible.

This was not caused because of the largely different codeset triggered by dropping `mcrypt` in favour of `openssl` in *Yii 2.0.3* ([release notes](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/85/yii-2-0-3-is-released/), [discussion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7215)), since that change was backward compatible. Instead *Yii 2.0.0* is not compatible with *Yii 1.1.x* though both utilizes `mcrypt`, because of the different output of encryption methods:

- *Yii 1*: `[IV][ciphertext]`
- *Yii 2*: `[keySalt][MAC][IV][ciphertext]`

where `[keySalt]` is a random key, `[MAC]` is the message authentication code, `[IV]` is the initialization vector and `[ciphertext]` is the real encrypted data itself. Since the decryption algorithm in *Yii 2* is not prepared for the input generated by *Yii 1*, they are not compatible. The solution of *Yii 2* is considered superior, since it detects more easily if the data was tampered.

Summarized if you would like backward compatibility, you have 2 solutions:

1. Use *Yii 1* and *Yii 2* together as described in the [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html).
2. Use only the relevant decryption method from *Yii 1*. This of course requires some changes (not just copy-paste), since the original code is dependent on the *Yii 1* framework.

Here, this should work:

```
use yii\helpers\StringHelper;

function yii_legacy_decrypt($data,$key=null)
{
    $module=@mcrypt_module_open('des','', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,'');
    $key=StringHelper::byteSubstr($key===null ? md5(Yii::$app->security->getRandomString(32)) : $key,0,mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($module));
    $ivSize=mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($module);
    $iv=StringHelper::byteSubstr($data,0,$ivSize);
    mcrypt_generic_init($module,$key,$iv);
    $decrypted=mdecrypt_generic($module,StringHelper::byteSubstr($data,$ivSize,StringHelper::byteLength($data)));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($module);
    mcrypt_module_close($module);
    return rtrim($decrypted,"\0");
}
```